# How to design a score or signature function based on the time series data

Tags: statistics, time-series, signal-processing, data-mining

I want to design a score or signature function based on a time series signal. Usually, the signal has ups and downs.

For a given time window, I desire to design the score function based on the number of times it fluctuates, the duration of the fluctuations, and the magnitude of the fluctuations. I am wondering what kind of math I can use to design the function. I am not sure if the statistical features (mean, median, and so on) would be enough to design unique function such that two time windows would be distinguishable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Summary statistics will not give you what you want... but it can still be useful.

Things you can try:

1. Zero crossings on the signal will give you **number of fluctuations**. You'll have to use some central tendency value to move the signal about the 0 line in order to do this. Alternatively you can use FFT on the original to find the harmonic frequency as part of the score.
2. Could define the **duration of fluctuations** as the difference between zero crossings divided by two (since one fluctuation will reach the 0-line twice).
3. **Magnitude** can be done by finding the local minima and maxima - check out some packages with peak finding functions. You might want to use the mean or median to rule out local minima and maxima that fall on the wrong side of the line. Alternatively, finding the zero crossings on the derivative signal and then mapping them back to the original will give you all the local minima and maxima as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.